getting weird shaping using curves on objects

i am trying to do this shape but
is not working

how can i do?
https://blend-exchange.com/b/qk1BJ9SV

There are many issues to be solved in order to make it work:
Both curve and mesh objects have some rotation and non uniform scaling, you have to apply their rot and scale:
Select the curve in obj mode, press Ctrl A > Apply Rot and Scale.
Do the same for the mesh object.

Then both object should have the same origin location:
Select the mesh, press Shift S > Cursor to selected.
Right click on the curve obj > Set Origin > Origin to 3D cursor.
Then go to edit mode, select all control points, set their Mean Radius to 1, and their Mean Tilt to -90.

Now you can add the Array Modifier (toward Z), and the curve modifier (Deform Axis Z).

